# Error trying to write a row in google sheets using API v4

Tags: java, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to write a row to a sheet using java and Google Sheets API v4.  I'm getting an error that I just can't understand.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The values passed are:

> sRange = '09/03/2017 11:01:13 PM'!A1
>   body = {majorDimension=ROWS, values=[[Test ID, Test Name, Run ID, Status, Run Duration, Execution Date, Execution Time]]}

Here is the trouble code:

```
outputValues = Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList("Test ID", "Test Name", "Run ID", "Status", "Run Duration", "Execution Date", "Execution Time"));
sRange = "'" + sSheetName + "'" + "!" + sHeaderRow;
body = new ValueRange().setValues(outputValues).setMajorDimension("ROWS");
result = service.spreadsheets().values().update(sSpreadsheetID, sRange, body).setValueInputOption("RAW").execute();
```

And the result:

```
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Requested writing within range ['09/03/2017 11:01:13 PM'!A1], but tried writing to column [B]",
    "reason" : "badRequest"
  } ],
  "message" : "Requested writing within range ['09/03/2017 11:01:13 PM'!A1], but tried writing to column [B]",
  "status" : "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think sRange should be using [A1 notation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts#a1_notation):

Something that looks like:

```
SheetName!A1:B2
Sheet1!A1
```

Check the link for more info.

Comment: Thank you for this, it put me on the right track!  What I needed was for sRange to be 1:1 (the whole first row), not A1.  Reading somewhere else in the google docs said that A1 represents the columns starting in A1 until the end (row if setMajorDimension("ROWS"), column if setMajorDimension("COLUMNS").  That seems to not be the case when it comes to rows.  Changing A1 to 1:1 fixed the issue!

Answer (score 13):

Got this error due to character issues in the sheet title. Removing spaces, dashes, and colons in the sheet titles and replacing them with underscores fixed it.

Comment: Thank you for this, it's so unobvious! My sheet was not created because of ":" character in sheet name.

Comment: Saved me so much aggravation, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Change your Sheet name to some simple version of it (without special symbols).
Helped in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I have been on this for some time now, in my case i was trying to update more than 2 fields in a row and i specified range as A1:B1 this only depicts 2 rows to be updated. I changed it to just A1 and it worked.

So let your range be:

```
SheetName!A1
```